# Error Creating Calculated Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Whenever I attempt to create a new calculated column in one of my lists, I am unable to save my new fields and get the error message: "Could not save field changes to the server."

I am able to create other types of columns, just not the calculated column. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the formula of calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a calculated column, you need to make sure the formula that you use is valid and there is no error for it. So, check your formula firstly. To narrow down, you can also set the formula is like :

```
=[Title]
```

If you still are unable to create the calculated column, you can provide your formula, and I will test it on my side.